# Saving Message Body to SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am receiving a message from a number. The format is below

"LAT: 14.471590 LONG: 120.984222 BATTERY: 35"

What I am trying to do is splitting the message body through a colon(:). Whenever I receive a message, the app toasts the details. Right now, I want to pass those data into SQLiteDatabase.

**This is my code for the SmsReceiver class:**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            String senderNumber = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                senderNumber = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                String message = sms.getMessageBody();
//                String[] separatedSMS = message.split(":");


                Toast.makeText(context, senderNumber + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendSMStoDatabase(sms, context);

            }

        }
    }

        public void sendSMStoDatabase(SmsMessage sms, Context context) {

            DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            String message = sms.getMessageBody();
            String[] separatedSMS = message.split(":");

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put("date", mydate);
        values.put("lat", separatedSMS[1]);
        values.put("long", separatedSMS[3]);
        values.put("battery", separatedSMS[5]);


            db.insert("locationDetailModel",null,values);

        }
```

**I am getting an error. The logcat says "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException" length=4 index=5.  Whenever I comment out** *values.put("battery", separatedSMS[5]);* **It wont display any error but is not inserting into my database.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would work if you split with space as a delimeter and not `":"`.
Try this:

```
String[] separatedSMS = message.split("\\s+");
```

It will create this array:

```
["LAT:","14.471590","LONG:","120.984222","BATTERY:","35"]
```

and you take the items in indexes `1`, `3` and `5`.
As it is right now, your code creates this array:

```
["LAT"," 14.471590 LONG"," 120.984222 BATTERY"," 35"]
```

and the values you need are not separated from other strings.